# Problem with overlapping divs on mobile device

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I'm using the class `vh-100` to make a multiple screen / section design. Idea being it's Step 1, 2 etc..

Seems to work absolutley fine on a desktop device, but when shrinking screen down to a sm device, overything seems to overlap.

I am using flex utils to align-items to the center of the section, but it overlaps on a mobile.

JS Fiddle can be seen here : https://jsfiddle.net/km3v12gz/

Any ideas or reasons why this would happen?

HTML is :

```
<section id="step-1" class="vh-100 align-items-center d-flex position-relative">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 mb-4 mb-sm-0">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <h2 class="mb-4">Select an option</h2>
                        <a class="button -primary u-block-mobile d-inline-block mr-2 mt-1 mt-sm-0" href="#">Sell</a>
                        <a class="button -primary u-block-mobile d-inline-block mb-2 mt-1 mt-sm-0" href="#">Rent</a>
                    </div><!-- /.text-center -->
                </div><!-- /.col-sm-8 -->
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <h2 class="mb-4">Enter your postcode</h2>
                    </div><!-- /.text-center -->
                    <input class="postcode form__input -light w-100 mb-3 text-center" name="postcode" type="text" placeholder="Enter Postcode">
                    <button class="button -secondary w-100 find-address" type="submit">Find Address</button>
                    <div class="hidden-addresses mt-3 mb-3" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <select class="addresses">
                                    <!-- /jQuery Populate -->
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /.row -->
                    </div><!-- /.hidden-address -->
                    <div class="hidden-address mt-3 mb-3" style="display:none;">
                        <p>Address of Property:</p>
                        <div class="property-address">
                            <!-- /.jQuery Populated -->
                        </div><!-- /.property-address -->
                    </div><!-- /.hidden-address -->
                    <div class="d-block mt-2">
                        <a href="#">Enter your address manually</a>
                    </div><!-- /.d-block -->
                </div><!-- /.col-sm-4 -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </section>

    <section>
        <div class="vh-100 align-items-center d-flex position-relative flex-grow-1">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="text-center mb-4">
                        <h3>Choose a date &amp; time</h3>
                    </div><!-- /.text-center -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <strong class="d-block mb-4">February
                                                                            / March
                                                                        2020
                                </strong>
                            </div><!-- /.text-center -->
                        </div><!-- /.col -->
                    </div><!-- /.row -->
                    <div class="pl-2 pr-2 pl-sm-5 pr-sm-5">
                        <div class="row seven-cols">
                                                                                        <div class="col-md-1 mb-4">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                                                                    <div class="d-block mb-4">
                                                <span class="c-dark f-bold">Sa</span>
                                            </div>
                                                                                <a class="d-inline-block p-2 data-select-block w-100 date-selection" href="#" data-date="2020-02-22">
                                            22
                                        </a>
                                    </div><!-- /.text-center -->
                                </div>
                                                                                            <div class="col-md-1 mb-4">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                                                                    <div class="d-block mb-4">
                                                <span class="c-dark f-bold">Su</span>
                                            </div>
                                                                                <a class="d-inline-block p-2 data-select-block w-100 date-selection" href="#" data-date="2020-02-23">
                                            23
                                        </a>
                                    </div><!-- /.text-center -->
                                </div>
                                                                                            <div class="col-md-1 mb-4">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                                                                    <div class="d-block mb-4">
                                                <span class="c-dark f-bold">Mo</span>
                                            </div>
                                                                                <a class="d-inline-block p-2 data-select-block w-100 date-selection" href="#" data-date="2020-02-24">
                                            24
                                        </a>
                                    </div><!-- /.text-center -->
                                </div>
                                                                                            <div class="col-md-1 mb-4">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                                                                    <div class="d-block mb-4">
                                                <span class="c-dark f-bold">Tu</span>
                                            </div>
                                                                                <a class="d-inline-block p-2 data-select-block w-100 date-selection" href="#" data-date="2020-02-25">
                                            25
                                        </a>
                                    </div><!-- /.text-center -->
                                </div>
                                                                                            <div class="col-md-1 mb-4">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                                                                    <div class="d-block mb-4">
                                                <span class="c-dark f-bold">We</span>
                                            </div>
                                                                                <a class="d-inline-block p-2 data-select-block w-100 date-selection" href="#" data-date="2020-02-26">
                                            26
                                        </a>
                                    </div><!-- /.text-center -->
                                </div>
                                                                                            <div class="col-md-1 mb-4">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                                                                    <div class="d-block mb-4">
                                                <span class="c-dark f-bold">Th</span>
                                            </div>
                                                                                <a class="d-inline-block p-2 data-select-block w-100 date-selection" href="#" data-date="2020-02-27">
                                            27
                                        </a>
                                    </div><!-- /.text-center -->
                                </div>
                                                                                            <div class="col-md-1 mb-4">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                                                                    <div class="d-block mb-4">
                                                <span class="c-dark f-bold">Fr</span>
                                            </div>
                                                                                <a class="d-inline-block p-2 data-select-block w-100 date-selection" href="#" data-date="2020-02-28">
                                            28
                                        </a>
                                    </div><!-- /.text-center -->
                                </div>
                                                                                            <div class="col-md-1 mb-4">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                                                                <a class="d-inline-block p-2 data-select-block w-100 date-selection" href="#" data-date="2020-02-29">
                                            29
                                        </a>
                                    </div><!-- /.text-center -->
                                </div>
                                                                                            <div class="col-md-1 mb-4">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                                                                <a class="d-inline-block p-2 data-select-block w-100 date-selection" href="#" data-date="2020-03-01">
                                            01
                                        </a>
                                    </div><!-- /.text-center -->
                                </div>
                                                                                            <div class="col-md-1 mb-4">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                                                                <a class="d-inline-block p-2 data-select-block w-100 date-selection" href="#" data-date="2020-03-02">
                                            02
                                        </a>
                                    </div><!-- /.text-center -->
                                </div>
                                                                                            <div class="col-md-1 mb-4">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                                                                <a class="d-inline-block p-2 data-select-block w-100 date-selection" href="#" data-date="2020-03-03">
                                            03
                                        </a>
                                    </div><!-- /.text-center -->
                                </div>
                                                                                            <div class="col-md-1 mb-4">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                                                                <a class="d-inline-block p-2 data-select-block w-100 date-selection" href="#" data-date="2020-03-04">
                                            04
                                        </a>
                                    </div><!-- /.text-center -->
                                </div>
                                                                                            <div class="col-md-1 mb-4">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                                                                <a class="d-inline-block p-2 data-select-block w-100 date-selection" href="#" data-date="2020-03-05">
                                            05
                                        </a>
                                    </div><!-- /.text-center -->
                                </div>
                                                                                            <div class="col-md-1 mb-4">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                                                                <a class="d-inline-block p-2 data-select-block w-100 date-selection" href="#" data-date="2020-03-06">
                                            06
                                        </a>
                                    </div><!-- /.text-center -->
                                </div>
                                                                                        <div class="col-12 mt-3 mb-3">
                                <div class="row slots">
                                    <!-- /.jQuery -->
                                </div><!-- /.slots -->
                            </div><!-- /.col-12 -->
                        </div><!-- /.row -->
                    </div><!-- /.pl-5 -->
                </div><!-- /.col-6 -->
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="text-center mb-4">
                        <h3>Your Details</h3>
                    </div><!-- /.text-center -->
                </div><!-- /.col-6 -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.align-items-center -->
    </section>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can set .vh-100{height:100% !important;} in mobile screen

Comment: @vadivela That's already set in the bootstrap-4 css : height: 100vh !important;
I suspect it's something to do with flex

Comment: Yes but remove height 100vh because canot occupy in all content in mobile device so need to scroll

Comment: can you set height:auto !important